# How to exclude main directory/home page from rewriting rule in htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can not figure out how to exclude home page from rewriting. 
In other words, .htaccess treats "example.com" as "example.com/user/index.php?name=" so it displays user specific content instead of my main page. I've tried bunch of things and nothing worked as I expected.

```
RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
 RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
 RewriteRule ^about/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /about/index.php?p=$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
 RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login/?$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/register/?$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about/?$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9.]+)/?$ /user/index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Hopefully you guys understand what my problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules look fine, the `+` qualifier in your regex should make it so it won't match just the `/` request. You can maybe try adding this right below `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?:index\.php|)($|\ )
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```